# Как дождаться, ожидать загрузки изображения?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log('get IMG:')
let img = new Image();
img.src = "https:​/​/...../​8.jpg"; 
console.log('img:', img)
console.log('До onload..')
img.onload = function() {
    console.log(`Изображение загружено, размеры ${img.width}x${img.height}`)
};
console.log('После onload..')
```

В консоли вижу следуюшее:

```
get IMG:
img: <img src=​"https:​/​/...../​8.jpg">​
До onload..
После onload..
Изображение загружено, размеры 1920x1280
```

По консоли видно, что загрузка происходит только после того, как изображение загружено. Можно ли как-то дождаться загрузки и не бежать дальше?

Comment: В синхронном коде не получится все остановить. Перенесите нужный функционал в img.onload. Так же можно попробовать переписать с использованием асихнронных фукнций, но суть будет примерно такая же - синхронный код запустит асинхронную фукнцию и побежит дальше, а уже в асинхронной можно ждать ответы от других асинхронных фукнций и не бежать далее по коду.

Comment: @SwaD, я боялся именно это услышать... Жаль...

Comment: Штош, классический дубликат классического вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290)